# FindFragmentById in Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I used 2 tutorils from Joe Rock for implementing [SlidingTabLayout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Rr0ZCvX_Zs&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l&index=10)  and using [google maps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6Q0olRPsus&index=40&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l) in Xamarin.

Both works fine as i follow the tutorials but whhen i wanna combine these i get errors.

I can't get the FindFragmentById working.

**MainActivity**

```
 public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity
{
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SlidingTabScrollView mScrollView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        mScrollView = FindViewById<SlidingTabScrollView>(Resource.Id.sliding_tabs);
        mViewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewPager);

        mViewPager.Adapter = new SamplePagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
        mScrollView.ViewPager = mViewPager;
    }

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.actionbar_main, menu);
        return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}

public class SamplePagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> mFragmentHolder;

    public SamplePagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fragManager) : base(fragManager)
    {
        mFragmentHolder = new List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment>();
        mFragmentHolder.Add(new GooglemapFragment());
        mFragmentHolder.Add(new ProfileFragment());
        mFragmentHolder.Add(new EventsFragment());
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return mFragmentHolder.Count; }
    }

    public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentHolder[position];
    }
}



public class ProfileFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    private EditText mTxt;
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Frag2Layout, container, false);

        mTxt = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
        mTxt.Text = "Fragment 2 Class :)";
        return view;
    }

    public override string ToString() //Called on line 156 in SlidingTabScrollView
    {
        return "Profile";
    }
}

public class EventsFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    private Button mButton;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Frag3Layout, container, false);

        mButton = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        return view;
    }

    public override string ToString() //Called on line 156 in SlidingTabScrollView
    {
        return "Events";
    }
}
```

GoogleMapFragment

```
public class GooglemapFragment : Fragment,IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private MapView mView;
    private SupportMapFragment mFragment;
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.GoogleMap,container,false);
       // mFragment = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("map") as SupportMapFragment;
       // mFragment.GetMapAsync(this);

        FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.map).GetMapAsync(Activity); 
       // return view;

            return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        googleMap = mMap;
    }
```

The only thing i adjusted is that i don't use a sepperate function but i entered it in OnCreateView.
Could someone please help me, it's important!

Thx in advance

Comment: FindViewByiD not working in which class?

Comment: Is doesn't work in GoogleMapFragment. the tutorial shows it in a Activity but not in a fragment. Al the examples that is find online aren't working with the slidingtablayout... I use the Android.support.v4.App.Fragment because the SlidingTabLayout uses this... The FindFragmentByTag gives nullreferenceException.

Comment: why you are not inflating layout in GoogleMapFragment class,,?

Comment: I tried so much different solutions that i was forgotten to take it out of comment.